# Yeoman scaffolding: Unable to find local grunt

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I just want to scaffold a simple god damn AngularJS application. But hey... it seems like nothing in the Javascript Developer World is possible without installing thousands of different libraries and whatever you call them.

I use Windows 7 and run "yo angular" on my application folder. Everything worked fine until I entered "grunt serve" in my console. And yay there comes the next dubious error message "Unable to find local grunt", although I followed the [introduction video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDB-jm8MWro) here step by step. But for some reason Windows user or just me are the only person on earth who get the error. Mac users seem to be invincible.

Im sorry for this writing style but Im pretty frustrated. I try to learn AngularJS and its TDD but every tutorial throws tons of errors when I try it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried running 'npm install'?